# File and folder with same name

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How do I make it so this:

```
www.example.com/services
```

Will point to this file:

```
/services.html
```

but this:

```
www.example.com/services/pocket-pool
```

Will point to this directory:

```
/services/pocket-pool.html
```

I have these rewrite rules in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^\.]+)$ $1.html [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, your nearly have your solution, you just have to extend it to take care of the second situation you want to handle:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^\.]+)$ $1.html [L]

RewriteRule ^/?services/(\w+)/?$  /services/$1 [END]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/?services/(\w+)/?$  /services/$1 [L]`
Didn't solve the problem. I am still getting 403 Forbidden error on:
`www.example.com/services`
The .htaccess file still points - services (folder) > services.html
Isn't there already implemented way to make sub-folders with files in html?
And just because I am removing the extension of files via .htaccess, it's causing absolute mess.

Comment: HTTP status 403 is something totally different! You never mentioned that in your question, _why not?_ 403 means "permission denied", not that the resource does not exist. Sounds like you have an issue with the permissions of your files in the physical file system. Or that you have a rule implemented that actually denies the access.

Comment: Folders are given 0755 permission and files are with 0644 permission. There is no problem with the permissions of the files, because I can easily fix the 403 error with renaming services.html to index.html and adding it to the /services folder. But as I mentioned, I want alternative - without adding index page to sub-directory.

Comment: Again: a http status 403 is _not_ caused by a missing file. There has to be something wrong with the permissions. Maybe some `<Directory ...>` based rules in your host configuration?